# DQL to remove a subgroup from a group in Documentum?

Tags: dql, documentum

Does anyone know how to remove a subgroup from a group in Documentum using DQL?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ALTER GROUP group_name DROP members
```

screenshot from DQL Reference Manual:

[image: screenshot from DQL Reference Manual]